# How to work with custom scopes and AndroidInjection.inject() in dagger 2

Tags: android, dagger-2

I want to create dagger 2 custom scope `@User` to manage user login state. **It should lives less than Application and more than Activity.** Before library have introduced `AndroidInjection.inject()` it not quite complex thing. You managed you components and create new component for this scope, when user logged in(from Application scoped component) and destroy it when user logged out. You can have something like this in activity `onCreate()`

```
LoginManager.getInstance()
    .getUserComponent()
    .newActivityComponentBuilder()
    .activity(this)
    .build()
    .inject(this);
```

But now all code generated and we have only Application, Activity and Fragment scopes. And I cant understand how to manage my custom scope with `AndroidInjection.inject()` where save this component and how put it in the middle of application and activity scopes.

Thanks for any useful tutorials, documentations or examples.